# How to draw vertical ticket shape in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to create a ticket shape. I have a source created with a semicircle on the X axis, but I had trouble converting it to the Y axis. How can I edit it to create a semicircle halfway between the right and left edges?

I tried something but I couldn't succeed:

```
private fun getTicketPathVertical(size: Size, density: Density): Path {
   val middleY = size.height.div(other = 2f) 
   val circleRadiusInPx = with(density) { circleRadius.toPx() }
    return Path().apply {
    reset()
   
    lineTo(x = 0F, y = 0F)

    lineTo(x = size.width, y = 0F)
   
    lineTo(x = size.width, y = middleY)
    
    arcTo(
        rect = Rect(
            left = size.width - circleRadiusInPx * 2,
            top = middleY - circleRadiusInPx,
            right = size.width,
            bottom = middleY + circleRadiusInPx
        ),
        startAngleDegrees = 270f,
        sweepAngleDegrees = -180F,
        forceMoveTo = false
    )
    
    lineTo(x = size.width, y = size.height)

    lineTo(0F, size.height)

    lineTo(x = 0F, y = size.height)
    arcTo(
        rect = Rect(
            left = 0F,
            top = middleY - circleRadiusInPx,
            right = circleRadiusInPx * 2,
            bottom = middleY + circleRadiusInPx
        ),
        startAngleDegrees = 90f,
        sweepAngleDegrees = -180F,
        forceMoveTo = false
    )
    
    lineTo(x = 0F, y = 0F)
 }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem

```
    private fun getTicketPathVertical(size: Size, density: Density): Path {
    val middleY = size.height.div(other = 2f) 
    val circleRadiusInPx = with(density) { circleRadius.toPx() }
    return Path().apply {
        reset()
       
        lineTo(x = 0F, y = 0F)
   
        lineTo(x = size.width, y = 0F)
        
        lineTo(x = size.width, y = middleY)
        
        arcTo(
            rect = Rect(
                left = size.width - circleRadiusInPx,
                top = middleY - circleRadiusInPx,
                right = size.width + circleRadiusInPx,
                bottom = middleY + circleRadiusInPx
            ),
            startAngleDegrees = 270f,
            sweepAngleDegrees = -180F,
            forceMoveTo = false
        )
       
        lineTo(x = size.width, y = size.height)

        lineTo(0F, size.height)

        lineTo(x = 0F, y = size.height)
        arcTo(
            rect = Rect(
                left = 0F - circleRadiusInPx,
                top = middleY - circleRadiusInPx,
                right = circleRadiusInPx,
                bottom = middleY + circleRadiusInPx
            ),
            startAngleDegrees = 90f,
            sweepAngleDegrees = -180F,
            forceMoveTo = false
        )
        
        lineTo(x = 0F, y = 0F)
    }
}
```

[image: shape]

Comment: How did you draw the dotted line exactly at the point matching those curves ?